# Private Maven Repository in Gitlab Error Couldn't download artifact: Missing

Tags: maven, gitlab, package, registry

Good afternoon, I am currently working with maven artifacts and I have them in a private maven repository, specifically in a gitlab, the question is that I am trying to download it and I get the following error:

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=tmve:encryptUtil-lib:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

The error I get:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:get (default-cli) on project user-profile: Couldn't download artifact: Missing:
[ERROR] ----------
[ERROR] 1) tmve:encryptUtil-lib:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   Then, install it using the command:
[ERROR]       mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=tmve -DartifactId=encryptUtil-lib -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
[ERROR]       mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=tmve -DartifactId=encryptUtil-lib -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   Path to dependency:
[ERROR]         1) org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-downloader-plugin:jar:1.0
[ERROR]         2) tmve:encryptUtil-lib:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR]
[ERROR] ----------
[ERROR] 1 required artifact is missing.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] for artifact:
[ERROR]   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-downloader-plugin:jar:1.0
[ERROR]
[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR]   gitlab-maven (https://TVDESSRVCCSKN01:37001/api/v4/projects/184/packages/maven, releases=false, snapshots=true),
[ERROR]   central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

This is the url of my project and this is how it is configured:

[image]

Since I'm behind a proxy, so I'm configuring my setting.xml in the .m2 folder:

```
<settings>
  <proxies>
      <proxy>
          <id>httpproxy</id>
          <active>true</active>
          <protocol>http</protocol>
          <host>10.162.64.36</host>
          <port>8080</port>
          <username>E10000</username>
          <password>xxxxxxx</password>
          <nonProxyHosts>localhost|127.0.0.0|172.28.2.107|TVDESSRVCCSKN01</nonProxyHosts>
      </proxy>
      <proxy>
          <id>httpCproxy</id>
          <active>true</active>
          <protocol>https</protocol>
          <host>10.162.64.36</host>
          <port>8080</port>
          <username>E10000</username>
          <password>xxxxxxx</password>
          <nonProxyHosts>localhost|127.0.0.0|172.28.2.107|TVDESSRVCCSKN01</nonProxyHosts>
      </proxy>
  </proxies>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>gitlab-maven</id>
      <configuration>
        <httpHeaders>
          <property>
            <name>Private-Token</name>
            <value>glpat-H8DbjfMbDBdf_BXeXj5y</value>
          </property>
        </httpHeaders>
      </configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <profiles>
```

Am I missing something to add in my command to get the dependency?